# C# Thread shared data

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need your help. I am just start learning threading topic.
Why printed 't2' twice?

```
        string text = "t1";
        Thread t1 = new Thread ( () => Console.WriteLine (text) ); 
        t1.Start();   // why do not print 't1'?
        text = "t2";
        Thread t2 = new Thread ( () => Console.WriteLine (text) );
        t2.Start();   // print 't2'
```

Output:

```
t2
t2
```

Comment: Run it enough times, and it actually might, occasionally

Comment: Instead of downvoting his question, just provide some suggestions to him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `text` is shared,. Thread t1 can start (in the background) and text can be assigned to  t2 before thread t1 could print anything. So Both print t2. If things occurred fast enough it might occasionally print t1 followed by t2.

Since a simple example was given I will give a simple solution (although not overly useful):

```
string text = "t1";
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine(text));
t1.Start();   // why do not print 't1'?
t1.Join(); // Wait for thread t1 to finish before continuing

text = "t2";
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine(text));
t2.Start();   // print 't2'
```

The difference is you wait for thread t1 to finish executing before assigning `text` a new value. I only give this example as how you can use Join to wait for a thread to complete.

A slightly more complex way is without using Lamda expressions. If you create a static function to do work you can pass a single parameter (any type of `object`) to the Start function on the thread:

```
    public static void DoPrint(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((String)data);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "t1";
        Thread t1 = new Thread(DoPrint);
        t1.Start(String.Copy(text)); // Pass a copy of text to Thread and start

        text = "t2"
        Thread t2 = new Thread(DoPrint);
        t2.Start(String.Copy(text)); // Pass a copy of text to Thread and start
    }
```

Notice how we make a copy of the text data before passing it in. That way even if `text = "t2"` does get done before thread t1 prints it won't matter because a copy was passed. Had the two Start lines been:

```
        t1.Start(text);
        t2.Start(text);
```

then we would have had the same issue as your original example for the same reasons. text is a string, and strings are a Class therefore they are passed by reference.

Comment: @GUImaniac94 Doing a sleep does not "fix" the problem, it just makes it less likely to happen. If you need a specific order of events to happen you must put some kind of stop in there that does not continue until the thing you are waiting for is done (that is what `.Join()` does). To compare the two ways, Your way: `Set value, start displaying, hope that it finishes displaying within the next 10ms, set value, start displaying` Michaels way: `Set value, start displaying, wait for it to finish dispaying, set value, start displaying`

Answer (score 0):

because before the t1 starts to work, the text variable assign to "t2", and then 2 and t1 starts to work simultaneously.